# Preventing a third party library from making a Toast message?

Tags: android, toast

I have to call a method in a third party library, and unfortunately the method makes an unnecessary Toast message. Is there a way to prevent the Toast message from showing (eg. temporarily turn off all Toast messages right before calling the method, and turning them on right after)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry. If you have the source code to the third-party library, you can cut out the offending `Toast`. Or, you can ask the developers of the library to get rid of the `Toast`, or make it configurable. Otherwise, you are stuck with it.